# Angular2 OR Expression Weird Result

Tags: javascript, angular, logical-operators

I am working with Angular2 and I have two boolean values: hidden, collapsed. I am printing them and their OR expression. The outputs are:

```
{{ hidden }}  {{ collapsed }} {{ hidden || collapsed }}

    false          false              false
     true          false               true
    false           true              false
```

I expect "true" when one of them is true, but it gives "false" if first one is "false" and second one is "true". Am I using the OR operator wrong? What is the problem here?

Edit: I tried "false && true" and it gives "true"

Comment: I can't reproduce it. https://plnkr.co/edit/A9rdr07hIWkkuTOlHxMy?p=preview

Comment: Here is the part of my code: <span style="float: right;">{{hide}} {{collapsed}} {{(hide && collapsed)}} {{hide || collapsed}}</span> and in the view: false true true false

Comment: Are the `hidden` and `collapsed` actually boolean values or are they values that are converted to `true` and `false` when used in the expression?

Comment: It works as expected: https://plnkr.co/edit/YVTS6g5FdjTqQ6IGFL68?p=preview

Comment: Are you sure that your variables are boolean? https://plnkr.co/edit/jew2XIaiBOf3615J2gqW?p=preview

Comment: They are both declared as boolean.

Comment: Hidden is an @Input() where collapsed is internal. Even if I gave them wrong values, I'm printing their && and || expressions in the same line but their && may become true while || is false. It is too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div>{{ type(hidden) }}  {{ type(collapsed) }}</div>
<div>{{ hidden }}  {{ collapsed }}</div>
<div>{{ hidden || collapsed }}</div>
```

and in your component

```
type(prop) {
  return typeof prop;
}
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nIoJZw1An0c3fgXsReok?p=preview)

Comment: It shows hidden as string. But I declared it as boolean and I gave it boolean value in the parent. Why it's a string?

Comment: I didn't understand it but I fixed it :) Thanks!

Comment: `hidden: boolean` works only in compilation time. It's just typescript wrapper over javascript. In runtime you can use any value for this property because it's javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, t&&f became true!
I found that the @Input that I inject from the html has to be with brackets [].
let's say your'e passing hidden from html tag, so it should be:

```
<app-input-user [hidden]="false"></app-input-user>
```

then hidden will be Boolean always. you can check it's type in the OnInit() and see :)